# Rotating text inside PDFPCell iTextPDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

I'm currently working for PDF Generator application in C# using iTextPDF library for my organization. How can I make a forty degree rotation to a text inside PDFPCell object. Can I do some tricks for making it work instead of manually using PDFContentByte method, such as ShowTextAligned.

I also provide the sample image about my letter criteria. Thanks.
[image: text is rotated using contentbyte class method.]

Comment: Creating a `PdfTemplate` then wrap it inside an image and rotate that image is one option. Creating a pattern color with the rotated text is another option. Using a `PdfPCell` event is the option you probably already found. Whatever works best depends on the exact use case. Looking at your screen shot, I don't see cells. Looking at your screen shot, I'd suggest using a pattern color, but I'm not sure if that's your exact use case.

Comment: If pdfpcell in itextsharp can make a 45 degree rotation, this case was solved early... lol... i will try to use pdftemplate as your suggestion...

Comment: hmm... I still do not get the information from "Creating a PdfTemplate then wrap it inside an image and rotate that image". Does it mean that I create rotated text template inside an image then using these template as watermark for creating the new pdf...?

Comment: @Bruno I try using your tutorial at [link](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/graphics/pattern-colors#1325-textpattern.java) . I get the point, but my result was ![pattern color](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h69tk71rn6okej5/pattern%20color.PNG?dl=0), and my code was: at  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yyih7vmwa1cunrg/pattern_color.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make a forty degree rotation to a text inside PDFPCell object. Can I do some tricks for making it work instead of manually using PDFContentByte method, such as ShowTextAligned.

This depends on the iText(Sharp) version you use.

**In version 5.x and earlier** you either have to use `ShowTextAligned` or you have to manipulate the content stream before and after writing the text to rotate the coordinate system. For drawing the text in a very high level API, therefore, you would pay by very low level content stream manipulation.

**In version 7**, on the other hand, arbitrary rotation of cell contents is possible in the high level API. For example you can do it like this (for iText/Java; porting to iTextSharp/.Net should be trivial):

```
try (   PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(target);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter)    )
{
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    Table table = new Table(new float[]{150, 150});
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.setRotationAngle(40 * Math.PI / 180.0)
        .add(new Paragraph("Test Watermark Text Copyright Test Only"))
        .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(cell.clone(true));
    table.addCell(cell.clone(true));
    table.addCell(cell.clone(true));
    document.add(table);
}
```

*([RotateCellContent.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/RotateCellContent.java))*

This results in

[image: screenshot]

---

This been said, though, your sample image seems to indicate that you simply want to repeat that rotated text again and again as a background. In this case a solution as suggested by @Bruno in his comment might be more apropos.

> I'd suggest using a pattern color, but I'm not sure if that's your exact use case.

This would have the additional advantage that the text would not get in the way of copy&paste / text extraction.

Comment: hmmm.... I think i must change my code to java since itext7 only appears in java. But, is it still possible using itextsharp to create this watermark...?

Comment: There is also going to be an iTextSharp 7 shortly, I bet.

Comment: i will wait it... :D

Comment: now, I will try with the new iText7 on .Net... Finally, it comes to c#...